# How can I modify this counter to not go below zero and not go past ten?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a dice roller generator project where it asks you to select how many dice you want to roll. So I am adding an increase/decrease counter so the user would be able to select, but I am currently having trouble trying to stop this counter from going below zero and going past ten. I tried using an if statement to break once it hit zero or ten but it did not work.

```
 from tkinter import *
 import tkinter
 import sys

 root = tkinter.Tk()
 root.geometry("200x200")
 root.title("Counter")

 counter = tkinter.IntVar()

 def increase():
       counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

 def decrease():
       counter.set(counter.get() - 1)


 lbl = Label(root, textvariable = counter)
 lbl.place(x=95, y=15)

 btn1 = Button(root, text="+", padx = 2, pady = 2, command = increase, fg="dark green", bg = 
 "white")
 btn1.place(x=110, y=10)

 btn2 = Button(root, text="-", padx = 4.1, pady = 2, command = decrease, fg="dark green", bg = 
 "white")
 btn2.place(x=70, y=10)

 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what did you try to limit it to the range 0-10?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min` and `max` to limit the values

```
def increase():
       counter.set(min(10, counter.get() + 1))

 def decrease():
       counter.set(max(0, counter.get() - 1))
```